# Where is "Align with view" for new objects in Blender 2.8

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to follow a [short video](https://youtu.be/NEUa1IA7NBQ?t=58).

In this video, the user creates a new plane and then checks "Align with view" in the "Add" panel:

[image]

I don't see this "Add panel" in Blender 2.8.

How could I achieve the same in Blender 2.8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.8 the last operation box is in the bottom left of the 3D View, open it and select *View* in the *Align* dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!